# Execute sudo command from swift

Tags: swift, macos, command-line, sudo

I am writing a sandboxed MacOS app in swift and I need to run a few command line commands. For most of the commands this isn't an issue. There's plenty of examples of how to execute that type of command. Where I'm having difficulty is running a command that requires `sudo`. Hard coding the password isn't an option because I have no way of knowing the user's password. I've looked into running it with AppleScript `with administrator privileges` but the user is never prompted for their credentials. If possible I would rather they not be prompted ever time I run the `sudo` command.

Comment: There are API's that provide the behavior of those CLI commands, and it's usually considered best practice (especially with a compiled language) to use those libraries. Trying to roll your own solution using fork-exec or similar is definitely an anti-pattern. If you want a shell script, write a shell script.

Comment: @Z4-tier what API provides the behavior of `sudo`?

Comment: Check out https://github.com/trilemma-dev/SwiftAuthorizationSample/tree/main